# URL value is not matching with a string value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have an URL like this:

`https://example.com/?contact%5Bcontext%5D=section`

I got the value of `contact[context]` like this:

```
let url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("contact[context]");
console.log("C: ", c);
```

`c` is giving me `section` but how will I compare like this?

```
if(c === 'section' ) {
  $("#user_has").css('display', 'block');
}
```

This is not working!!!!

Comment: Just in case, try using `if (c.trim() === 'section')`

Comment: ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null

Comment: That makes no sense if `console.log(c)` shows a value. Maybe it's a scope problem? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `if (c && c.trim() == 'section')`

Comment: Or you might want to remove the **strict** equality check: `===` .. and change it to `==`

Comment: @Cypherjac Why would that make a difference? There's no loose equalty check that would make this condition true.

Comment: @Barmar According to the OP, this: `console.log("C: ", c);` was giving "section" ... " `c` is giving me `section` " ..

Comment: @Cypherjac And how will a loose comparison solve it? What type conversion do you think he's missing by using strict equality?

Comment: Loose vs strict equality generally only makes a difference when you're doing things like comparing numeric strings with numbers, or different types of empty values.

Comment: Problem solved. with @Barmar.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Barmar